# In Django Stripe not allow to create a new Card

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, stripe-payments

Why stripe(version=2.55) doesn't allow me to create a new card.
its show me error `return super(StripeObject, self).__getitem__(k) KeyError: 'sources'` Whats wrong in my code?

I think error is here `stripe_card_response = customer.sources.create(source=token)`

```
class CardManager(models.Manager):
    def add_new_card(self, billing_profile, token):
        if token:
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(billing_profile.customer_id)
            stripe_card_response = customer.sources.create(source=token)
            new_card = self.model(
                billing_profile=billing_profile,
                stripe_id=stripe_card_response.id,
                brand=stripe_card_response.brand,
                country=stripe_card_response.country,
                exp_month=stripe_card_response.exp_month,
                exp_year=stripe_card_response.exp_year,
                last4=stripe_card_response.last4
            )
            new_card.save()
            return new_card
        return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are changed in **latest version of Stripe**. So i did this and it's working fine.

```
class CardManager(models.Manager):
    def add_new_card(self, billing_profile, token):
        if token:
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(billing_profile.customer_id)
            stripe_card_response = stripe.Customer.create_source(billing_profile.customer_id, source=token)
            print(stripe_card_response)
            new_card = self.model(
                billing_profile=billing_profile,
                stripe_id=stripe_card_response.id,
                brand=stripe_card_response.brand,
                country=stripe_card_response.country,
                exp_month=stripe_card_response.exp_month,
                exp_year=stripe_card_response.exp_year,
                last4=stripe_card_response.last4
            )
            new_card.save()
            return new_card
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `customer.source.create()`: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/v2.55.0/stripe/api_resources/customer.py#L17

Comment: latest version of stripe uses `stripe.Customer.create_source()`